# Slow query - how to improve query performance in AZure mysql

Tags: mysql, azure, query-optimization

**I have a three table. When I execute below query it takes 3 to 5 min.**

```
SELECT u.Id,cmc.completionstate,cmc.coursemoduleid
FROM User u
JOIN role_assignments ra ON  u.id =ra.userid
LEFT JOIN course_modules_completion  cmc ON u.id=cmc.userid  
LIMIT 1000000000
```

Execution Plan:

```
id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys             key                       key_len  ref                             rows    Extra
```

---

```
 1  SIMPLE       u       index   PRIMARY                   mdl_user_del_ix           1        (NULL)                          31018   Using index  
 1  SIMPLE       ra      ref     mdl_roleassi_use_ix       mdl_roleassi_use_ix       8        tpsmoodle_prod_moodle_new.u.id  2       Using index  
 1  SIMPLE       cmc     ref     mdl_courmoducomp_use_key  mdl_courmoducomp_use_key  8        tpsmoodle_prod_moodle_new.u.id  41
```

Comment: it is already optimal

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You have NO WHERE to limit the results.  Who can possibly use 1 Billion rows of output in their lifetime, much less today?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to improve the speed

- Scaling: Vertical / Horizontal
- Partitioning / Indexing: Improve "internal" structure
- Query: Selecting only required data `SELECT TOP(10)...`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be unused (except to validate that there is a row in `ra`).  Remove it:

```
JOIN  role_assignments ra  ON u.id =ra.userid
```

Much of the slowness is due to reaching into `ra`.  If you really need it, we can discuss whether an `EXISTS` would be an appropriate improvement.

Another point:  (This derives from the "2" in `EXPLAIN`.)  You are probably getting multiple identical output rows simply because there are many `ra` rows matching `ra.userid`.

The `LIMIT` probably had no effect; consider removing it.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  In particular, there does not seem to be any index *starting* with `userid` in `cmc`.  So, I recommend either of these:

```
INDEX(userid)
INDEX(userid,  completionstate, coursemoduleid)
```